# Using an input box to distill results from a GET request in React.js

Tags: reactjs, get, axios

I have a component which i'd like to be able to distill the results from a `GET` request using `axios` to itunes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import api from '../utils/api';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { artists: [], artistSearched: '' };
    this.handleSearchTermChange = this.handleSearchTermChange.bind(this);
    this.getArtists = this.getArtists.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getArtists(this.state.artists);
  }

  getArtists(artist) {
    this.setState(function() {
      return {
        artists: artist,
      };
    });

    api.getItunesArtists(artist).then(
      function(artists) {
        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            artists: artists,
          };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  handleSearchTermChange(event) {
    this.setState({ artistSearched: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Itunes Album Fetcher</h1>
        <form style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
          <input
            onChange={this.getArtists}
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter album name"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am thinking I'd have to rewrite the 'getArtists' method. 
But that didn't work.

```
 getArtists(artist) {
  this.setState(function() {
      return {
        artists: null
        artistSearched: handleSearchTermChange(artist),
      };
    });

    api.getItunesArtists(artist).then(
      function(artists) {
        this.setState(function() {
          return {
            artists: artists,
          };
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what isn't working from your question

Answer (score 0):

```
 render() {
 {artists, artistSearched} = this.state;
  const filteredArtists = artists.length && artists.filter(item => item.artistName.toLowerCase().includes(artistSearched.toLowerCase()))
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Itunes Album Fetcher</h1>
        <form style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
          <input
            onChange={this.getArtists}
            value={this.state.searchTerm}
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter album name"
          />
        </form>
      {filteredArtists.length ? <div> filteredArtists.map(item => item.artistName) </div> : <div> no artists searched </div>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

You never actually filtered the artists array with the search term. If everything else worked fine then filteredArtists will hold the artists that contain the same name as your search term.

`const filteredArtists = artists.length && artists.filter(item => item.artistName.toLowerCase().includes(artistSearched.toLowerCase()))`

item.artistName is just the attribute of the object you need to replace this with the name of the attribute returned from your request for every artist.